# Unzipping a file in node.js to a url path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zip, unzip

I'm making an application in the express framework where the user uploads a zip file and views it on the website. I already have uploading a single html file and viewing it; however, I can't seem to figure out extracting a zip file online. I can currently store the zip file in the database, but when it's pulled from the database it seems to be impossible to unzip it in to the url and not on my disk. Where do you think I should start with trying to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of this module: https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip - I have succeded in using it when user uploads file that must be unziped at server side. I think that docs for the native zlib API are missing or not yet supplied. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which zip format you're using, but one example of how it could work is with the zlib api:  http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

If you use that library to create a stream  you can write that stream to the response, in concept.  The bigger question in my mind is what do you mean by "unzip to a url"? If the zip is an archive w/ multiple files, what do you expect a user to see at that URL?